# Имитация роута в Angular

Tags: angular, angular6

Есть ангуляровское приложение. Есть потребность встроить его в другой сайт (не ангуляр) как виджет. Приложение одностраничное, но параметры принимает через роут. В случае с виджетом это мешает. Передать нужные параметры я могу через инпут параметры элемента виджета, но как мне имитировать роут?

Comment: что значит "имитировать"?

Comment: @overthesanity, имитировать, значит заставить приложение думать, что пользователь снавигировался куда либо с какими-либо параметрами. В общем, чтобы выполнилась вся логика, связанная с настройками роута.

Comment: зависит от приложения, в чем проблема работать с `window.location`? :)

Comment: @overthesanity да ни в чем, когда приложение открыто в отдельном окне. И не очень, когда приложение является виджетом на какой то левой странице/сайте.

Comment: ну окей, является виджетом, у вас нет доступа к `window.location`?

Comment: @overthesanity, конечно есть, но у сайта свой роут.

Comment: мы ходим кругами, еще раз спрошу, в чем проблема внутри angular приложения работать с `window.location`? :)

Comment: @overthesanity, представь, что у тебя есть приложение. Кое что у тебя завязано на роут /myroute?param1=1. Когда приложение запущено самостоятельно, все норм. Но когда приложение встраивают в другой сайт, у него свои роуты. Например, твой виджет встроили в гугл. Ты начнешь управлять его location?

Comment: если того требуют обстоятельства - конечно, я просто не до конца понимаю что такое виджет - iframe?

Comment: @overthesanity, виджет - это что то типа `<my-widget></my-widget>` встроенный в произвольное место на сайте.

Comment: просто уже накопилось больше 10 комментариев на тему, почему бы не использовать `window.location`, класс `Router` помогает управлять внутренним жизненным циклом навигации в Angular, он вам не нужен. Из коробки есть кроссплатформенный класс `Location`, который изолирует много полезной бизнес логики и позволяет напрямую не стучаться к `window.location`

Comment: @overthesanity мне не нужен window location, сайт-родитель не должен подстраивать свой роут под виджет